# How can I get Gradle to build dependencies before running my task?

Tags: gradle, plugins, dependencies

Background: I am trying to hook the compiler for my own domain-specific language into Gradle. The DSL is compiled to Java source code, so I have built a task that runs before the Java compiler. The compiler cannot currently handle multiple projects with dependencies, so I'm trying to add that.

My DSL has packages like Java that get mapped to identical Java packages. The same should be true for projects. In that case, for each project, the DSL sources get compiled to Java source code, as well as meta-data (a JSON file per compiled class, containing information from the DSL's type system that cannot be mapped to Java types). When project A depends on B, the DSL compilation process for A needs the meta-data files from B. That meta-data should be packaged as resources into the JAR file together with the generated and compiled Java code, as well as possibly hand-written and compiled Java code.

FoobarPlugin.groovy:

```
class FoobarPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        // create the compileFoobar task
        CompileFoobarTask task = project.getTasks().create('compileFoobar', CompileFoobarTask.class);
        task.group = 'build';
        task.setDescription('Compiles Foobar to Java code.');
        task.sourceDirectory = new File(project.projectDir, "src/main/foobar");
        task.outputDirectory = new File(project.getBuildDir(), "foobar-java");

        // compileFoobar must run before compiling Java code
        project.tasks.compileJava.dependsOn(task);

        // add the task's output folders as Java source folders
        project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += task.outputDirectory;
        project.sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs += task.outputDirectory;
        project.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += task.outputDirectory;
        project.sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs += task.outputDirectory;

        // Turn project dependencies into task dependencies. We have to delay this until the end of the configuration
        // phase because project dependencies are not fully known until then.
        project.gradle.addBuildListener(new BuildAdapter() {
            @Override
            void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {
                project.configurations.compile.each {
                    task.dependencyOutputs += it
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

CompileFoobarTask.groovy:

```
class CompileFoobarTask extends DefaultTask {

    @InputDirectory
    File sourceDirectory;

    @InputFiles
    List<File> dependencyOutputs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OutputDirectory
    File outputDirectory;

    @TaskAction
    void run() {
        FileUtils.write(new File(outputDirectory, "timestamp"), "" + System.currentTimeMillis(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

}
```

build.gradle from project A:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: foobar.gradle.FoobarPlugin

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':b')
}
```

build.gradle from project B:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: foobar.gradle.FoobarPlugin

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
}
```

Test runs and output:

```
martin@xyz:~/git-repos/gradle-test$ ./gradlew clean a:compileFoobar
adding dependency /home/martin/git-repos/gradle-test/b/build/libs/b.jar to task task ':a:compileFoobar'

> Task :a:compileFoobar
running task ':a:compileFoobar'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date


martin@xyz:~/git-repos/gradle-test$ ./gradlew clean b:compileFoobar
adding dependency /home/martin/git-repos/gradle-test/b/build/libs/b.jar to task task ':a:compileFoobar'

> Task :b:compileFoobar
running task ':b:compileFoobar'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 469ms
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date


martin@xyz:~/git-repos/gradle-test$ ./gradlew clean a:compileJava
adding dependency /home/martin/git-repos/gradle-test/b/build/libs/b.jar to task task ':a:compileFoobar'

> Task :a:compileFoobar
running task ':a:compileFoobar'

> Task :b:compileFoobar
running task ':b:compileFoobar'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 487ms
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 2 up-to-date


martin@xyz:~/git-repos/gradle-test$ ./gradlew clean b:compileJava
adding dependency /home/martin/git-repos/gradle-test/b/build/libs/b.jar to task task ':a:compileFoobar'

> Task :b:compileFoobar
running task ':b:compileFoobar'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 471ms
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

As you can see, even though I add b.jar as a dependency to a:compileFoobar, Gradle won't build that JAR before running a:compileFoobar. The Java plugin seems to do something different because running a:compileJava WILL build b.jar first. What do I have to do to achieve the same for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to explicitly create a **Task dependency** between consumer project's `compileFoobar` task and the producer project's `jar` task (in your example where `project a` depends on `project b`, you need to create task dependency `a:compileFoobar -> b.jar`)

You can achieve this in your custom plugin, by checking if the current project has dependencies of type [ProjectDependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ProjectDependency.html): if so you create the task dependency accordingly.

Code sample (in your plugin `apply()` method):

```
        // Turn project dependencies into task dependencies. We have to delay this until the end of the configuration
        // phase because project dependencies are not fully known until then.
        project.gradle.addBuildListener(new BuildAdapter() {
            @Override
            void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {
                project.configurations.each { config ->
                    config.dependencies.each { dep ->
                        if (dep instanceof ProjectDependency) {
                            def producerProject = ((ProjectDependency) dep).dependencyProject
                            def producerJarTask = producerProject.tasks.jar
                            println " **** Project $project.name depends on $producerProject.name"
                            println "      => create dependency between $task to $producerJarTask"
                            task.dependsOn(producerJarTask)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Build execution:

```
$  ./gradlew clean a:compileFoobar
 **** Project a depends on b
      => create dependency between task ':a:compileFoobar' to task ':b:jar'
> Task :a:clean
> Task :b:clean
> Task :b:compileFoobar
> Task :b:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :b:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :b:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :b:jar
> Task :a:compileFoobar
```